# websphere 8 remote ejb NamingException

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, websphere-8

I am migrating some legacy code from old websphere to websphere 8, and I'm having problems in one of the classes calling remote EJB. Here is the code this class is using:

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
env.put("java.naming.provider.url", "corbaloc:iiop:" + server + ":" + port);

InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(env);
Object homeobj = ctx.lookup(cell/clusters/n1_cluster/ejb/ReportsHome);
```

The code throws exception on the line ctx.lookup, and here is the exception thrown:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Error during resolve
                at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1868) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1777) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookupExt(CNContextImpl.java:1434) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookup(CNContextImpl.java:616) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:165) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
                at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
                at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161) ~[na:na]
                at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:423) ~[na:1.7.0]
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: purge_calls:2131 Reason: CONN_ABORT (1), State: ABORT (5)
                at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.purge_calls(Connection.java:2130) ~[na:na]
                at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doReaderWorkOnce(Connection.java:3379) ~[na:na]
                at com.ibm.rmi.transport.ReaderThread.run(ReaderPoolImpl.java:130) ~[na:na]
```

How can I resolve this? I read somewhere this should be resloved using thinclient.jar, but I cannot find this jar in websphere 8, or in the old websphere

Comment: Check [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21407925) out looks like you may have port conflict on ORB_LISTENER_ADDRESS port.

Comment: Just checked the server. There are no port listener conflicts

Comment: Which process is making the request, and which server are you trying to connect to?  SSL is enabled by default for RMI/IIOP in 8.0, so have you tried disabling security in the new server (just to see whether it is a security-related issue)?

Comment: Thank you @Brett, changing RMI/IIOP configuration from SSL to TCP/IP did it. Thank you.

Comment: I made the suggestion so you could determine whether it was a security-related issue.  I suppose it depends on your environment, but you should probably investigate how to make the client work over SSL rather than just disabling SSL altogether.